# Why are x *and* z = 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following line of code:

```js
var y = 0

var x = y
var z = y

x = 3

console.log(x, y, x)
```

I set y to 0, x to y, and x to y, and then change x, but y remains unchanged, and z is changed. Why is z changing if y is unchanged, and how can I change x without changing z?

Comment: because in your console log there is x, y, X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to be printing `z`, not `x` again:

```js
var y = 0

var x = y
var z = y

x = 3

console.log(x, y, z)
```